# Why do both ng-model and name need to be supplied for ng-submit?

Tags: angularjs, ng-submit

In the following code, I am adding a customer to a table based on information from the form.

I found that the `ng-submit` will not send the form variables to `addCustomer()` unless the input element has both `ng-model` and `name` and they both have the same name, although I couldn't find this documented anywhere.

Why is this the case? And since this seems to be redundant, and I passing the variables correctly?

```
<html ng-app="mainModule">
    <head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>    
    <body ng-controller="mainController" style="padding: 20px 0">

        <div class="col-lg-12">

            <div class="panel panel-success" style="width: 500px">
                <div class="panel-heading">Add Customer</div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <form ng-submit="addCustomer()" role="form">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="firstName">First Name:</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="firstName" name="firstName"/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="lastName">Last Name:</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="lastName" name="lastName"/>
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Add</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel panel-info" style="width: 500px">
                <div class="panel-heading">Customers</div>
                <table class="table-striped table-bordered table table-hover">
                    <tr>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>First Name</th>
                        <th>Last Name</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr ng-repeat="customer in customers">
                        <td>{{customer.id}}</td>
                        <td>{{customer.firstName}}</td>
                        <td>{{customer.lastName}}</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>

        </div>
        <script>
                    var mainModule = angular.module('mainModule', []);
                            function mainController($scope) {
                                $scope.idCount = 1;
                                $scope.customers = [];

                                $scope.addCustomer = function () {
                                    $scope.customers.push({id: $scope.idCount++, firstName: this.firstName, lastName: this.lastName});

                                };
                            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just use ng-model and $scope to access the form data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you would create a customer object, and then bind ngModel to its properties.

In your ngController, initialize your newCustomer:

```
 var mainModule = angular.module('mainModule', []);
 mainModule.controller('mainController', function ($scope) {
       $scope.idCount = 1;
       $scope.customers = [];
       $scope.newCustomer = { id: $scope.idCount, firstName:'', lastName:''};
       $scope.addCustomer = function (customer) {       
            $scope.customers.push(customer);
            $scope.newCustomer = { id:++$scope.idCount, firstName:'', lastName:''}; 

       }; 
 }
```

In your HTML, bind ngModel to the customer's first name and last name poperties - unless you need to do form validation, the name attribute is not necessary.

```
<form ng-submit="addCustomer(newCustomer)" role="form">
       <div class="form-group">
            <label for="firstName">First Name:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="newCustomer.firstName" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="lastName">Last Name:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="newCustomer.lastName"/>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Add</button>
</form>
```